# Read out date range from CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, graph

I'm currently working on a PHP/AJAX script where you can search within a date range and get the search result in a graph. I've been literally tearing my hair out over this project, and now I feel like it's time to ask you guys.

To show the graph, I'm using a simple open-source plugin for PHP called pChart.
I'm able to show the graph, but I'm stuck with the putting-csv-searchresults-in-graph part.

stocks.csv:

```
2016-01-02,77.44539475

2016-01-03,77.04557544

2016-01-06,74.89697204

2016-01-07,75.856461

2016-01-08,75.09194679

2016-01-09,76.20263178

2016-01-10,75.2301837

2016-01-13,73.84891755

2016-01-14,75.0113527

2016-01-15,77.14481412

2016-01-16,77.33058367

2016-01-17,76.85652616

2016-01-21,75.39394758

2016-01-22,76.7763823

2016-01-23,76.64038513

2016-01-24,77.20512022

2016-01-27,76.66007339
```

To be able to search between dates in this CSV I believe I must put the results in an array, but I'm unsure how I would be able to put it into an array where I could read it out in the right order to put here:

```
$MyData->addPoints(array(<VALUES GOES HERE>),"Value"); // Value
$MyData->addPoints(array(<DATES GOES HERE>),"Labels"); // Date
```

Believe me, I've been googling a lot before coming here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should probably work for you:

```
    $stocks = array_map('str_getcsv', file('stocks.csv'));      

    $labels = array();
    $values = array();
    $from_date = '2016-01-15'; // SET THE START DATE HERE
    $to_date = '2016-01-18'; // SET THE END DATE HERE

    foreach($stocks as $stock){
        if(strtotime($stock[0]) >= strtotime($from_date) AND strtotime($stock[0]) <= strtotime($to_date)){ 
            $labels[] = $stock[0];
            $values[] = $stock[1];
        }
    }

  $MyData->addPoints($values),"Value"); // Value
  $MyData->addPoints($labels),"Labels"); // Date
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately I'm still unable to split up the dates and values for the dates and put them in the graph... Let alone the function that searches for the dates... :(

Comment: I have now updated my answer, and even tested that it worked... Not the graph, but the values separated from labels in two different arrays... just be sure that your CSV file is sorted the way you want to present them in the graph

Comment: You did it! Thank you so very much!
This worked just perfect out of the box. I can now search for the dates and show it in a graph. :)